# Replace a value of a field in a tuple in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have two data sets to join. Here is what they look like:

```
 Dataset 1
 ---#----#----#------------#----#-----#-----
 F1 | F2 | F3 | UID        | F4 | ... | F32
 ---#----#----#------------#----#-----#-----
 a1 | b1 | c1 | MD5 value1 | d1 | ... | foo1
 a2 | b2 | c2 | MD5 value2 | d2 | ... | foo2
 a3 | b3 | c3 | MD5 value3 | d3 | ... | foo3
 a4 | b4 | c4 | MD5 value4 | d4 | ... | foo4

 Dataset 2
 ----#-----#--------------#-----#-----#-----
 Z1  | Z2  | UID+Constant | Z3  | ... | Z62
 ----#-----#--------------#-----#-----#-----
 p1  | q1  | MD5 value1+C | s1  | ... | t1
 p2  | q2  | MD5 value2+C | s2  | ... | t2
 p3  | q3  | MD5 value3+C | s3  | ... | t3
 p4  | q4  | MD5 value4+C | s4  | ... | t4
```

Now I used explicit Field names to load both the datasets:

```
D1 = LOAD '/dataset1' USING PigStorage(',')
     AS (F1:chararray, F2:chararray, F3:chararray, UID:chararray, ... , F32:chararray);

D2 = LOAD '/dataset2' USING PigStorage(',')
     AS (Z1:chararray, Z2:chararray, UID_C:chararray, ... , Z62:chararray);
```

Now, I want to get the combined output from both the datasets when I join on UID value. So, I split the `UID_C` field in `D2` using `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`. Here is how I did that.

```
D2_SPLIT_UID_C = FOREACH D2 GENERATE *,
                    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(UID_C, '^(.*)\+(.*)$'))
                        AS (UID:chararray, C:chararray);
```

And then I join on `UID` on both the datasets.

```
JOINED_DATA = JOIN D1 BY UID, D2_SPLIT_UID_C BY UID;
```

All good till here, but now, I have to generate the output without the `UID_C` field. Instead, I need to replace it with the value of `UID`. Also, I do not need the `Constant(C)` in my final output.

So, I need to generate the data first from `D1` and then from `D2`. So here is the output header of my final output

```
---#----#----#------------#----#-----#-----#----#----#-----#----#-----#----
F1 | F2 | F3 | UID        | F4 | ... | F32 | Z1 | Z2 | UID | Z3 | ... | Z62
---#----#----#------------#----#-----#-----#----#----#-----#----#-----#----
```

This is where it gets ugly. I need to put all the fields from dataset1 and dataset2 again for my final `FOREACH GENERATE F1, F2, F3, UID, ...., F32, Z1, Z2, UID, Z3, ...., Z62`. This way, if my schema changes tomorrow, I will have to update it here as well.

Can't I replace the `UID_C` column value with the UID value and then I would just need to use `FOREACH GENERATE *` and I will be done?

Comment: If it's a constant and you only need the MD5, why the hell are you using a regex instead of just `SUBSTRING` with appropriate length?

Comment: We want the Constant as well later on for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [project-range](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#expressions) expression to define field ranges, e.g:
Skip UID_C as well as the constant after the MD5 sum:

```
D2_SPLIT_UID_C = FOREACH D2 GENERATE Z1 .. Z2, Z3 .. Z62, 
  FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(UID_C, '^(.*)\\+.*$', 1)) AS (UID:chararray);
```

Comment: But still doesn't solve my problem. Actually those field names are dummy. So, ````Z3 .. Z62```` is not possible.